# Restrict access dependent on environment variable

Tags: apache-2.4, environment-variables

Trying to be clever and allow access depending on an environment variable. It doesn't seem to work (no errors, the expression is always false).

---

#### What I tried:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ...

  <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options       Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order         allow,deny

    <If "reqenv('ENVIRONMENT_STATE') == 'dev'">
      allow from 1.22.333.0/24
      deny from all
    </If>
    <Else>
      allow from all
    </Else>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

#### Expected behavior:

If `ENVIRONMENT_STATE` is set to `'dev'`, then restrict all access except from the mentioned IP.

---

#### Sources:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#else
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use the .htaccess file for IP restrictions. The reasons being:

- You can source control it.
- No server restart required when adding or removing IP addresses.
- If you accidentally lock yourself out you can always FTP in and edit the file to restore access.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400154/htaccess-deny-all-allow-only-one-ip) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, but I'm not sure how this answered the question regarding the deny depending on the `ENVIRONMENT_STATE` variable value? Could you please elaborate?